# fbconnect play framework 2.0

Tags: fbconnect, playframework-2.2

I spent an hour of my time to search how to use fb-connect module with play framework 2.2.0... I tried to install it using this command : play install fbconnect-0.6 but it says that "This is not a play application!"

Is everyone can help me to resolve this problem please ?!

Thx in advance..

@mayes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fbconnect plugin you are referring to is most likely for play 1, there is no "play install" operation in play 2 so it is looking for a project called "install" which does not exist, hence the error message.